# Alinear un botón en el BOTTOM_CENTER en JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Estoy intentando como un loco posicionar el botón que he creado en la interfaz gráfica en el centro-abajo del panel.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, el botón está en el eje 0,0.
Investigando por internet y demás, tengo entendido que puedo posicionarlo son un setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER)...

Esto es lo que tengo:

```
Button button = new Button("START");
button.setPrefSize(75,25);
button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
```

```
//Configurar panel
        root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.BLACK,null,null)));
        root.getChildren().add(imageView);

        //Agregar escena 1
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,600,600);
        stage.setTitle("Indole Hourglass");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.getIcons().add(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("images/fox.jpeg")));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no me equivoco, el método `setAligment` no afecta a la posición del  componente sobre el que lo aplicas, sino a sus hijos. Es decir, debes definir el alineamiento en el contenedor del botón y no en el botón en sí.

Comment: Lo tenía en hecho con un Pane, para poder hacerlo con setAlignment tendría que ser con StackPane. Ya lo conseguí y no me gustó el resultado .